# Moving (not copying) remote files after download with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have this script that downloads all .txt and .log files. But I need to move them to another directory on the server after the download.

So far I just keep getting errors like *"cannot move "file" to "/file"*.

```
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
    $sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
    $sessionOptions.HostName = "host"
    $sessionOptions.PortNumber = "port"
    $sessionOptions.UserName = "user"
    $sessionOptions.Password = "pass"

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.DisableVersionCheck = "true"
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        $localPath = "C:\users\user\desktop\file"
        $remotePath = "/"
        $fileName = "*.txt"
        $fileNamee = "*.log"
        $remotePath2 = "/completed"
        $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath)
        $directoryInfo = $session.ListDirectory($remotePath2)

        # Download the file
        $session.GetFiles(($remotePath + $fileName), $localPath).Check()
        $session.GetFiles(($remotePath + $fileNamee), $localPath).Check()

        $session.MoveFile(($remotePath + $fileName, $remotePath2)).Check()
        $session.MoveFile(($remotePath + $fileNamee, $remotePath2)).Check() 

    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many problems in your code:

---

The `targetPath` argument of the [`Session.MoveFile`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_movefile) method is a path to move/rename the file to.

So, if you use the target path `/complete`, you are trying to move the file to a root folder and rename it to the `complete`. While you probably want to move the file to folder the `/complete`, and keep its name. For that use the target path `/complete/` (or the `/complete/*` to make it more obvious).

Your current code fails, because you are renaming the file to a name of an already existing folder.

---

You actually have the same bug in the `.GetFiles`. You are downloading all files (both `*.txt` and `*.log`) to the folder `C:\users\user\desktop` and save them all to the same name `file`, overwriting one another.

---

You have brackets incorrectly around both arguments, instead of around the first argument only. While I'm no PowerShell expert, I'd actually say you are omitting the second argument of the method completely this way.

---

Further, note that the `MoveFile` method does not return anything (contrary to the [`GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles)). So there's no object to call the `.Check()` method on.

---

The `MoveFile` (note the singular, comparing to the `GetFiles`), moves only a single file. So you should not use a file mask. Actually the present implementation allows a use of the file mask, but this use is undocumented and may be deprecated in future versions.

Anyway, the best solution is to iterate the list of actually downloaded files, as returned by the `GetFiles` and move the files one by one.

This way you avoid race condition, where you download set of files, new files are added (which you didn't download) and you incorrectly move them to the "completed" folder.

---

The code should look like (for the first set of files only, i.e. the `*.txt`):

```
$remotePath2 = "/completed/"

...

$transferResult = $session.GetFiles(($remotePath + $fileName), $localPath)
$transferResult.Check()

foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
{
    $session.MoveFile($transfer.FileName, $remotePath2) 
}
```

Note that this does not include a fix for the `$localPath`, as I'm not sure, what the path `C:\users\user\desktop\file` actually mean.

---

There's actually a very similar sample code available:
[Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to make sure your process has rights to move files to the new directory?

Comment: No matter what i try to do in properties to change read or write settings i always get this error "SITE CHMOD "xxx" /completed

Answer (score 0):

I am doing what Martin suggest in here with success.

But I have been stuck for sometimes.

After running "session.MoveFile()", the file in origin folder is gone, but it is not showing in destination folder.

The files will showing to destination after "session" disposed automatically after some time period (around 30 minutes I guess).

To avoid this confusion,  dispose the session.
Like this :

session.Dispose();

I know this is trivial, but I hope that you don't fall to same problem.

Comment: That's hardly possible. Moving a file is an atomic operation. No matter what bug you have in your code, it cannot happen that the file disappears. Either the move fails and file stays where it was, or the move succeeds and the file in the new location.

Comment: Sorry Martin.
What I meant is the file gone from origin but not directly showing on destination.

The file will eventually showing to destination after the session is disposed automatically.